# Redis Lua Script Calculate Sum

Tags: redis, lua

The following Lua Script for Redis always returns "(integer) 0" whereas it should return the sum of the values for the specified keys:

```
local items = {}
local matches = redis.call('KEYS', '{example_h}:example_k:*')
for _,key in ipairs(matches) do
    local val = redis.call('GET', key)
    items[#items+1] = val
end
local sum = 0
for _,int in ipairs(items) do
    sum = sum + tonumber(int)
end
return sum
```

The following trimmed script returns the values correctly:

```
local items = {}
local matches = redis.call('KEYS', '{example_h}:example_k:*')
for _,key in ipairs(matches) do
    local val = redis.call('GET', key)
    items[#items+1] = val
end
return items
```

```
1) "-0.05251131847951142"
2) "0.05693711576626384"
3) "0"
4) "-0.71846248019776347"
5) "0.00734199740789916"
```

Why is "sum = sum + tonumber(int)" not performing the calculation?

Comment: "(integer) 0" how did this string output? If you converted the result to an integer, it would be zero.

Comment: Changing the final line to "return tostring(sum)" has resolved the issue. I'm unsure why Redis is always expecting to return a integer (in this case, 0)??